# Bing map conflicts when used with Google map API

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I am using google map in my application. I have an application regarding to property sales and purchase for that I have used google map.

But now I have to add Bird's Eye view in it. Since there is no such a concept in google map api, I have decided to use Bing map.

But when I implemented a bing map in it, It affected the functionality of google map.

Means it conflicted the google map.

Can't I use bing map with google map?

Have any Idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit about how the conflicts manifest?  Are you seeing error messages?  What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: When I am using bing map, it just disable the functionality of google map. I can't access it properly. It just hangs my application.

Comment: I have got the solution for this.
You can refer my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use both Google map and Bing map in your application, then you can use different iframe for each.

It will prevent conflicting between each other...

Thanks to brian.behling for their post on Google help forum.

Here is the link for that :

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=0d28300c9c0f585e&hl=en&fid=0d28300c9c0f585e00048bf69617bd9e

I have answered this question just because anyone else can refer to that easily...

Regards.